# High count of packet retransmissions/Dups over IPSEC/VPN

Tags: vpn, ipsec, wireshark, mtu

I'm running IPSEC-VPN (AES256/SHA256/DH14) tunnel between a PaloAlto PA-500 and a Fortigate 110C via Internet (10MBit up/down guaranteed both sides - latency between 40 and 50ms).

90% connections are ICA/HDX connections (TCP 1494 and 2598) for XenDesktop connections.

The connection is working not very well. The ICA-sessions are quite stable most of the time but some hangs and freezes from time to time and very low file transfer speeds of physical clients. So I captured data at a tunnel end and saw that I have a huge amount of retransmissions/duplicates ACKs/reassembly errors/...). There are about 15 to 40% of all packets through my tunnel are Dups ands Retrans packets.

Can anybody help me where to start my debugging/solving? I think this are the causes of my problems - right?

e.g. ICA-Traffic
[image: e.g. ICA-Traffic]

e.g. RDP-Traffic
[image: e.g. RDP-Traffic]

Thanks a lot for any help!

Stony

Comment: have you tried to set DF bit to 1?

Comment: Have you solved in some way ?